# Alternative for Forloop in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop

I am in very big trouble because of this  forloop & Dropdownlist.
I am developing Inventory Management System & in that ERP I am creating Online Purchase Order & Sell Order.
For SEll Order Page.
Suppose I have 10 Different Product In my warehouse and I want to sell 2,000 quantity from each product
Now I have list of 10 products on the same page & I have to bind Total 20,000 quantity to the dropdownlist for each product & also I have to looping through it for the 20,000 which will kill the performance of the page

Like this

```
Product DDl
A :    2,000
B :    2,000
C:    2,000
D:    2,000
E:    2,000
F:    2,000
G:    2,000
H:    2,000
I:    2,000
J:    2,000
```

Suppose A to J are the list of product & to right side : are the total quantity that I have to bind to ddl by using loop.

One Can only Select Inhand quantity from the Warehouse by using the Dropdownlist.
So that One cannot sell more than Inhand Quantity.
Suppose I have 20,000 quantity in my warehouse then I have to loop thourgh  20,000 times in Forloop for 
Inserting that much quantity in my dropdownlist.

Because of 20,000 times looping though the forloop Page is not resopnding 
Can anyone suggest me the best possible way to achieve this

Comment: If you are ordering a bunch of the same thing, is there any reason you can't have a quantity field in your order table, fill that with the quantity ordered and simply subtract the quantity ordered from the quantity in the warehouse?

Comment: Why do you need to loop through 20K times? you said `I have 20,000 quantity in my warehouse` does that mean 20K different items? if yes .. are they stored in a DB table? if yes, then just do a `select *` and bind the result to your dropdown. ELSE, provide more clarification about how you are getting data? what's the datasource presentation?

Comment: Rahul now please look at the question it is not that too easy that you have just use the select statement & select statement will solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing or how.

If you need to check that someone can't sell more `items` than he has, you can simply ask the DB for the total of items he has , and make sure it's bigger.

You can also save and cache that value, or have it is another field in a table.

Having said that, and assuming it still takes some time to fetch, you can (should? depends on you) use async calls so your gui isn't waiting for the operation to finish.

Comment: Sorry but I did not got your answer

Comment: Noctis, suppose if I am have to bind directly that 20,000 quantity Is there anyway so that I can get 1 to 20,000 number in the database so that I can directly bind that to the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

Change your input field. Instead of a `DropDownList`, you can use a `Textbox` with a `NumericUpDown` control attached. You can set the maximum and minimum values of this to match your inventory system.